# Can I hold the iterator of a new inserted element of a std::list and use the iterator to erase the element later safely?

Tags: c++, stl

Or hold the return of `list.begin ()` to erase the just `push_front`ed element later?

Or hold the return of `list.end ()` to erase the just `push_back`ed element later?

Comment: It depends on how you use your list in between. I would suggest looking at the different methods in [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) and reading the notes on iterator validity.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi, there is a std::list.remove, but it is quit inefficient.

Comment: @T.L, you'd need to use std::list::erase to erase an element by position using an iterator.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi, thanks, I plan to use erase, but I can't make sure if I can use the iterator of new element later safely. (In fact, I can use it safely later)

Comment: @T.L - You can use it safely as long as you do not modify your list in a way that invalidates your iterator e.g: removing that element from the list or clearing the entire list. Adding to the list or removing elements other than the element that your iterator points to is fine.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Iterators of list are not invalidated after insertion/push_back/push_front.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if an iterator returned by `begin()` will always "point" to the first element, then the answer is no.

An iterator from a list points to the specific node in the list, and if you add more nodes in front the iterator you have will no longer be pointing to the first node, but the same node it always have been pointing to.

If you are asking if an iterator will be invalidated by adding more nodes to the list, then the answer is also no. Like I said in the previous paragraph, iterators points to single nodes, no matter their position in the list. The only way to invalidate an iterator to a list node is to remove the node from the list.

---

Graphically it could be seen something like this:

You ave a list, and get an iterator to the first node in the list, it would be something like this

```
 +---------+
 | begin() |--\
 +---------+   \     +--------+
                >--> | node 1 |
+----------+   /     +--------+
| iterator |--/      | node 2 |
+----------+         +--------+
                     | ...    |
                     +--------+
```

Then lest say you add two node in in the front, then it will look like:

```
 +---------+         +------------+
 | begin() |-------->| new node a | 
 +---------+         +------------+
                     | new node b |
+----------+         +------------+
| iterator |-------->| node 1     |
+----------+         +------------+
                     | node 2     |
                     +------------+
                     | ...        |
                     +------------+
```

Comment: I mean the iterator returned by begin () at the pushed time.

Comment: @T.L The iterator returned by `begin()` will always be the node first in the list *when you call the `begin()` function*. If you add new nodes to the front, then `begin()` will return the new front of the list. Also, if you add new nodes to the beginning of the list, the old iterator you have save will no longer point to the beginning of the list, you iterator will no longer be equal to `begin()`.

Comment: I see. It will not change when I keep a copy of it.